# Show that the set $((-1,1),\le)$ is not isomorphic with the set $((-1,0)\cup(0,1),\le)$ where $\le$ is the usual order on $\Bbb R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Show that the set $((-1,1),\le)$ is not isomorphic.with the set $((-1,0)\cup(0,1),\le)$ where $\le$ is the usual order on $\Bbb R$, $(-1,1),(-1,0),(0,1)$ are half-intervals.

My idea is that we loose all the couples $(a,0)$ and $(0,a), \forall a \in (-1,0)\cup (0,1)$ from the first set, is this proof enough? or there is stronger more formel one?

Thank you.

Comment: Equinumerous is not the same as isomorphic.

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: Equinumerous = "same number", that is, the same cardinality. Isomorphic = "same structure", which then depends on what kind of structure is being discussed, in this case linear order. The two sets are in fact equinumerous, but the linear orders are not isomorphic.

Comment: Ok I will edit the question, thank you

Answer (score 2):

The first set has the least upper bound property.
The second set does not.